# Android - EditText to int after pressing button click issue

Tags: android, casting

Is it a proper casting? After pressing button the app is closing. If I toggle comment on second line (`height = Integer`) then it works fine.

```
public void onClick(View v) 
{
    EditText tHeight = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.tbHeight);
    height =  Integer.parseInt(tHeight.getText().toString());
}
```

Full log if you mean this log:

```
02-09 14:41:58.941: I/dalvikvm(15417): Turning on JNI app bug workarounds for target SDK version 5...
02-09 14:42:03.918: D/AndroidRuntime(15417): Shutting down VM
02-09 14:42:03.918: W/dalvikvm(15417): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40bf11f8)
02-09 14:42:03.918: E/AndroidRuntime(15417): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-09 14:42:03.918: E/AndroidRuntime(15417): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
02-09 14:42:03.918: E/AndroidRuntime(15417):    at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
02-09 14:42:03.918: E/AndroidRuntime(15417):    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:359)
02-09 14:42:03.918: E/AndroidRuntime(15417):    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
02-09 14:42:03.918: E/AndroidRuntime(15417):    at com.example.as.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:64)
02-09 14:42:03.918: E/AndroidRuntime(15417):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3558)
02-09 14:42:03.918: E/AndroidRuntime(15417):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14157)
02-09 14:42:03.918: E/AndroidRuntime(15417):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
02-09 14:42:03.918: E/AndroidRuntime(15417):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-09 14:42:03.918: E/AndroidRuntime(15417):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-09 14:42:03.918: E/AndroidRuntime(15417):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
02-09 14:42:03.918: E/AndroidRuntime(15417):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-09 14:42:03.918: E/AndroidRuntime(15417):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-09 14:42:03.918: E/AndroidRuntime(15417):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
02-09 14:42:03.918: E/AndroidRuntime(15417):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
02-09 14:42:03.918: E/AndroidRuntime(15417):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: can you provide some log?

Comment: height is a field or marked final?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that `Integer.parseInt` can throw `NumberFormatException`. That is probably what is happening.

Do you have a number on the `EditText`? It's likely that if there's a space it won't parse as well. Try this `tHeight.getText().toString().trim().replace(" ", "");` to remove any spaces.

Also on the XML layout, make sure to mark the input type as numeric.

And last but not least, make sure to put a `try{ }catch(NumberFormatException e){ }` to make sure it won't crash

Comment: I think that should work, because i have space there. I'll try :) Um nothing :( it wasn't space. I have null value there. I put some number and nothing.  02-09 14:39:25.769: E/AndroidRuntime(15203): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""

Comment: Ok it works. I write android:inputType="number" in TextView instead EditText. And also i forgot to comment rest of casting. So this one works and it stops on other. Thank you.  I cant vote up...I need 15 rep. Sorry